# How do I lock rows with matching values together when sorting? [R]

Tags: r

I have a `data.table` that looks like this:

```
> datatab
                    variant_id           transcript_id is_NL counts nrows
     1: chr17_35725138_G_A_b38 chr17_35773405_35778887     0  25419   556
     2: chr17_35725138_G_A_b38 chr17_35773405_35778887     1   1299    24
     3: chr17_35725138_G_A_b38 chr17_35773405_35778887     2     56     1
     4: chr17_35726682_T_C_b38 chr17_35773405_35778887     0  25419   556
     5: chr17_35726682_T_C_b38 chr17_35773405_35778887     1   1299    24
    ---
110918:   chr8_2195895_C_G_b38    chr8_2129233_2140722     1   6428   125
110919:   chr8_2195895_C_G_b38    chr8_2129233_2140722     2    596     7
110920:   chr8_2195895_C_G_b38    chr8_2143457_2144663     0  24887   538
110921:   chr8_2195895_C_G_b38    chr8_2143457_2144663     1   7054   125
110922:   chr8_2195895_C_G_b38    chr8_2143457_2144663     2    637     7
                      tissue
     1: Adipose_Subcutaneous
     2: Adipose_Subcutaneous
     3: Adipose_Subcutaneous
     4: Adipose_Subcutaneous
     5: Adipose_Subcutaneous
    ---
110918:          Whole_Blood
110919:          Whole_Blood
110920:          Whole_Blood
110921:          Whole_Blood
110922:          Whole_Blood
```

I want to sort it in a why where the lowest `counts` values where `is_NL == 0` are at the top, and it ascends towards the bottom. However, I want to keep together rows where `variant_id` and `transcript_id` are the same between each other, such as the first three rows:

```
                    variant_id           transcript_id is_NL counts nrows
     1: chr17_35725138_G_A_b38 chr17_35773405_35778887     0  25419   556
     2: chr17_35725138_G_A_b38 chr17_35773405_35778887     1   1299    24
     3: chr17_35725138_G_A_b38 chr17_35773405_35778887     2     56     1
```

How would I go about doing this?

EDIT
I implemented Akrun's suggestion below:

```
> datatab[order(variant_id, transcript_id, is_NL != 0)]
                    variant_id           transcript_id is_NL counts nrows
     1: chr10_60842447_A_G_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443     0  32968   685
     2: chr10_60842447_A_G_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443     1   1440    20
     3: chr10_60842447_A_G_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443     2    337     1
     4: chr10_60846892_G_A_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443     0  33157   690
     5: chr10_60846892_G_A_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443     1   1251    15
    ---                                                                  
111179:  chr9_91400473_C_T_b38  chr9_91298077_91325317     1   3018    59
111180:  chr9_91400473_C_T_b38  chr9_91298077_91325317     2    105     2
111181:  chr9_91400964_C_T_b38  chr9_91298077_91325317     0  26051   544
111182:  chr9_91400964_C_T_b38  chr9_91298077_91325317     1   3018    59
111183:  chr9_91400964_C_T_b38  chr9_91298077_91325317     2    105     2
                 tissue
     1: Muscle_Skeletal
     2: Muscle_Skeletal
     3: Muscle_Skeletal
     4: Muscle_Skeletal
     5: Muscle_Skeletal
    ---                
111179:        Skin_Sun
111180:        Skin_Sun
111181:        Skin_Sun
111182:        Skin_Sun
111183:        Skin_Sun
```

It did something but I'm not sure what. It did not order the row triplicates by lowest `counts` value at `is_NL == 0`, since `32968` is more than `26051`. I'm going to look into `order` to learn more about it, though.

Comment: I think you may nee to sort by the first two columns, and then the 'is_NL' `datatab[order(variant_id, transcript_id, is_NL)]`

Comment: The rows are to be treated as essentially one row but they're just different dimensions of the same `variant_id` x `transcript_id` datum. I would just like to sort the `variant_id` x `transcript_id` triplets with the lowest `counts` value where `is_NL == 0` at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `order`

```
library(dplyr)
datatab[order(variant_id, transcript_id, is_NL != 0)]
```

Comment: How would I use `rleid` in this instace? Not familiar with that command. Do you have any pointers?

Comment: @CelineDion `rleid(c(0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 5) == 0)` creates a group here and it is used in the `order`ing

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had time to revisit it. I'm having trouble understanding exactly how I'm supposed to implement `rleid` to index my rows

Comment: @CelineDion  Please check if the results you expected are correct

Comment: @CelineDion  Not sure why I didn't add the `rleid` in the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204622/discussion-between-celinedion-and-akrun).